# How to call the define variable in another file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a define variable is a string like this

```
#define kyouTubeLink  @"<iframe width='%d' height='%d' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showsearch=0' frameborder='0' scrolling='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
```

so how to call this variable in another file.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference a variable that is `#define`-d in another translation unit. You can put the definition in a header file, and `#include` it from any translation unit that needs the definitions.

Since the definition is a C string literal, though, you would be better off defining a constant `extern` variable for it, putting the declaration in a header, defining it in *one* of your translation units, and using everywhere else:

Common header (say, "YouTubeShared.h"):

```
extern const NSString* kyouTubeLink;
```

First translation unit (e.g. "AppDelegate.m" or whatever is a file that is better suited to hold the constant)

```
#include "YouTubeShared.h"
const NSString *kyouTubeLink = @"<iframe width='%d' height='%d' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showsearch=0' frameborder='0' scrolling='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
... // More things go here
```

Second translation unit:

```
#include "YouTubeShared.h"
... // More things go here
NSString *res = [NSString stringWithFormat:kyouTubeLink, 123, 456];
```